# How to create single sign in for my 3 applications

Tags: authentication

I have three web applications. Each of these applications has its own specificity and account database.

I'd like to develop a common login page. The account would be common to all applications. For example, `login.fr?redirect=myApp2` is my centralized connection and redirects to my second application

How to do it?

I thought of 2 solutions:

- Use OAuth2 or OpenID Connect. But I don't think that's what it's for: it's for a centralized connection, internal to our products. Not an identity provider for external applications.
- Simply: a connection that holds all user information and generates a JWT for applications

Comment: You could certainly host your own identity provider, e.g. the open-source Keycloak.

Comment: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/130087/handling-multiple-applications-behind-one-login

Comment: @Turdie It's a UX question. Here, it's a dev / protocol question